# Add unversioned file as new wersion in TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have the following problem.

I have a group of source code files.

I there has been some parallel development and testing, now I have different (unversioned) files with the same names. I need them to become a new version of the versioned codes (with keeping the history of previous changes).

Can you please tell me how to do it? I do not have much experience with SVN.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the situation. Do you mean you've checked out a working copy from as SVN repository, then developed in a copy of such folder where you had removed the `.svn` directory? If so, you need to move your changes to the original location so you can commit them.

Answer (score 0):

By some safe experimenting I found out that, if I have one file with code in my SVN folder and second file (named identically) with the new version of code. Simple copy and paste (neccessary to choose option "rewrite the file") solves the problem. After committing the file contains new version (can be checked with "Diff with previous version" functionality).

This procedure works as well for group of files or folders.